# Get JSON objects in SQL

Tags: sql, json

I am storing a JSON in my database as a string and would like to read parts of it back for a stored procedure. The string looks like below and I have thought of trying to do substring like

```
  `SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(DisplayData, CHARINDEX('"filePath":"', DisplayData) + 12, LEN(DisplayData)) as filePath
  FROM bridge.BridgeAttachment`
```

But have no idea on how to end it to get what I want.

```
{"IsSelected":"N","Caption":"","Figure":2,"filePath":"/upload/20018/984a8fb.png","attachmentid":77,"attachmentTypeCode":"Field","fileSize":18325,"mimeType":"image/png"}
```

Comment: there are *a lot* of code examples and explanations out there for this... what database are you in?  did you want a single value or the whole string parsed to a table (expensive)?

Comment: Don't store JSON strings in a database. Store the data in columns, then you don't get this sort of problem.

Comment: Which database are you using? PostgreSQL has a Json column type

Comment: Using MSSql. I am storing the JSON string because what I have a need for many and varied pieces of data that I don't want to create new columns for. I'd start with getting single values, like the file path in my example, and then work my way from there.